# Highcharts will not display data

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, highcharts, mtgox

I am pulling data from the mtgox api, I can see in my console that all the data is reaching my chart correctly.  However, I cannot get the data to display on my chart.  Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
     var now = new Date();
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Bitcoin Price',
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: MtGox.com',
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: Date.UTC(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
        }
    },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Price'
                },
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Bitcoin',
                data: series
            }]
        });

    }  
  });

});
```

Comment: I tried it without the quotes but the data still isn't displaying.  Just a blank chart shows with the title and the x and y axis labels.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you've wrapped part of your success callback in `$(function () {...})`. This attaches an event handler that will be fired when the DOM is ready. You won't need it in your AJAX success callback since that is already wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Remove the `$(function () {...})` wrapper in your success callback and see if your chart works then.

**EDIT**

Also, you need to pass a year, month, and (optional) date to the `Date.UTC` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fP58F/1)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation, but after I removed it my chart still doesn't display the data.

Comment: are you sure that the `price` array has data in it?

Comment: @evann You need to pass a year, month, date to the `Date.UTC` function; I've updated my answer and provided a working example for you

Comment: I just updated my code, the new code you see now shows the price on the chart, however, the date and time are wrong.  How do I get it to show the current date and time?

Comment: @evann You'll need to pass the current date and time to the `Date.UTC` function

Comment: I've updated my example to include getting the current date: http://jsfiddle.net/fP58F/1/

Comment: i updated my code according to your answer, but I now get the following error:

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
[Break On This Error]  

pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day

foundation.min.js (line 13, col 12)

Comment: whoops I was forgetting the comma after the date.utc, however even after I added it it still gives me the wrong dates, I dont understand why it's different from yours on jsfiddle

Comment: What do you mean by wrong dates? Maybe problem is with months - remember that months started from 0, not from 1. Should be` getMonth() -1`. Also, try to set `useUTC: false`, for Highcharts.